# Execute a (click) or (keyup) event method only if the value matches with pattern in angular 4+

Tags: angular, design-patterns

Below is the HTML code, the keyup will be triggered only if the input field value matched with the pattern.

```
<input (keyup)="checkPatternMatch(ProjectName)" type="text" #ProjectName="ngModel" name="pro-name" class="form-control" pattern=".*\S+.*">


pattern=".*\S+.*"
```

this pattern should atleast contains a single character (it does not consider space as a character).

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

Here, I have added a condition which will check if there is no error then only call your function `checkPatternMatch`.

```
<input (keyup)="projectName.errors ? '' : checkPatternMatch(ProjectName)" type="text" #projectName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="projectValue" name="projectName" class="form-control" pattern=".*\S+.*">
```

**Following things I have added:**

```
1. (keyup)="projectName.errors ? '' : checkPatternMatch(ProjectName)"
2. [(ngModel)]="projectValue"
```

Find [**StackBlitz here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhzyg3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the validity flag into your function and handle it in the component.

app.component.html

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="exec(projectName.valid)" #projectName="ngModel" pattern=".*\S+.*">
```

app.component.ts

```
exec(isValid) {
    if (isValid === true)
        // code
    else
        // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the template variable as a argument in the function.

```
(keyup)="checkPatternMatch(ProjectName)"
```

Function code

```
checkPatternMatch(Name)

  {

    if(Name.errors == null)

        // code...

  }
```

if the user gives space inside the input field the keyup event will be triggered but in function, the if condition will get failed (because of the pattern mismatch). so the code inside the if block will not executed.

Answer (score 0):

[here is an example of how you could handle that with a directive](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-teebst?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmatch-pattern.directive.ts)

The trick is to pass in a function, that you trigger when the pattern matches the input value.

```js
doSomething() {
  console.log('matching pattern');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="aaa" [appMatchPattern]="doSomething">
```

```js
import { Directive, Input, EventEmitter, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMatchPattern]'
})
export class MatchPatternDirective {

  @Input() appMatchPattern: Function;

  pattern: RegExp;
  el: HTMLInputElement

  constructor(private er: ElementRef) {
    this.el = er.nativeElement;
    this.pattern = new RegExp(this.el.getAttribute('pattern'));
  }

  @HostListener('keyup')
  onKeyup() {
    if (this.el.value.match(this.pattern)) {
      this.appMatchPattern();
    }
  }
}
```